# Qual a origem dos "sonetos"? Quem começou usar este este estilo literário?

Tags: origem-histórica, literatura, figura-de-estilo

Qual a origem dos "sonetos", quem começou usar este estilo literário?

Comment: CIMend, estás perguntando da origem de *soneto* ou da origem do soneto? Fiquei confuso.

Comment: Soneto da poesia. Qual a diferenca das duas palavras que comentou? Nao sao iguais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [soneto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soneto#Hist%C3%B3ria) surgiu na Sicília, Itália, na primeira metade do século XIII e sua invenção é creditada a Giacomo da Lentini.

Fontes:

- [História e Teoria do Soneto](https://www.academia.edu/7687243/1_ORIGEM_E_FINALIDADE_DO_SONETO) (cap. 1) — Cruz Filho, anotado por Glauco Mattoso
- [Teoria do soneto: de Giacomo da Lentini ao século XXI](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/pesquisa/DetalheObraForm.do?select_action=&co_obra=154296) — Solange Rech ([e-print](https://www.livrosgratis.com.br/ler-livro-online-145696/teoria-do-soneto--de-giacomo-da-lentini-ao-seculo-xxi))

Comment: Há menções na rede sobre origens anteriores, mas que parecem carecer de fundamento. Também a possível origem francesa seria equivocada, baseada numa tradução incorreta: _Pellissier: "É conhecida a voga que adquiriu o soneto, por volta do meado do século XVII. Não é este poema de origem provençal, como geralmente se tem acreditado; a palavra "son" ou "sonnet", muito antiga na língua dos trovadores, aplica-se a qualquer espécie de canto e designa, sobretudo, as composições líricas que eram cantadas ao som de instrumentos musicais. A forma moderna do soneto é invenção italiana_ [Cruz Filho].